# Error code accessing SASHELP.ZIPCODE.DATA in SAS Studio

Tags: error-handling, virtualbox, sas-studio

I am using SAS Studio in VirtualBox, when attempting to access the zip code data SASHELP file in SAS Studio libraries I get the following error:

ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for file SASHELP.ZIPCODE.DATA.

Any idea why or how to resolve?

Comment: How did you try to access it?

Comment: Clicking on the file within the column of files.